# Make a segment of a segmented control invisible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it possible to make one segment of a segmented control invisible?

Comment: If you want only one segment then why to use segment control, you can directly use a button..

Comment: I am using a segmented control in the view and there happen to be another button in the same view that looks exactly like a segment of the segmented control. So I was trying to do it with a single segmented control. If I could make a segment invisible, I get the view exactly as I want it to be.

Comment: @JohnValiaveettil you can easily customize a UIButton to anything you want. and there is no way to remove a segment from the segment control. The minimum segment will be 2 only. you cannot reduce further.

Comment: Thats what I should be doing. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Though it seems there is no way to hide a segment in a segment control, you could remove a segment from the segment control using *`removeSegmentAtIndex:animated:`* method. You need either *`insertSegmentWithImage:atIndex:animated:`* or 
*`insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:`* method to insert the segment again.

Instead of hiding/showing a segment you could consider enabling/disabling it using *`setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex:`* method.

Answer (score 21):

You can't hide it but you can **make its width very very small** which will make it invisible for the user. It has to be > 0 because 0 = automatic width.

```
[yourSegmentedControl setWidth:0.1 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

To be in the safe side, also disable it to reduce the chance of selection to zero.

```
[mapTypeSC setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,try this it's working for me ,It's only one line of code ,

**Objective C**

```
 [self.segmentControl removeSegmentAtIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

**Swift**

```
 segmentControl.removeSegment(at: 0, animated: false)
```

The code remove **0** index segment and show only one segment invisible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of the results above worked for me. The one reducing the width did not work because I had set

```
control.segmentDistribution = .fillEqually
```

What worked for me was resetting the segment control's count. Here an example when the data source for the segments is `["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]`. Imagine you want to remove "Option 2":

```
var segmentDataSource = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

segmentDataSource.remove(at: 1)

let oldSelectedSegment = control.selectedSegment

control.segmentCount = segmentDataSource.count
control.selectedSegment = max(0, oldSelectedSegment - 1)
for (index, option) in segmentDataSource.enumerated() {
    control.setLabel(option, forSegment: index)
}
```